# Auto tab and copy/cut/paste clipboard in Neovim

Tags: neovim

I'm new to nvim and I have some questions when I use nvim

1. I often work with Javascript and I want nvim can tab automatically like VS Code when I press enter. How can I do that?
2. How can I cut/copy/paste with clipboard in Neovim, Should I use some plugin?

This is some Pluging I'm using:

```
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'drewtempelmeyer/palenight.vim'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'w0rp/ale'
Plug 'prettier/vim-prettier', { 'do': 'npm install' }
Plug 'yuezk/vim-js'
Plug 'maxmellon/vim-jsx-pretty'
Plug 'kassio/neoterm'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'alvan/vim-closetag'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'raimondi/delimitmate'
Plug 'ekalinin/dockerfile.vim'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
```

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For auto tab, I suppose you mean auto indentation. You can turn on autoindent and smartindent option.

```
set autoindent smartindent
```

To use clipboard for cut and paste, set clipboard option

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

See `:h clipboard` for more info.

Comment: Thanks, `set clipboard+=unnamedplus` worked for me. Remember everyone, the paste command is `p`, and the copy command is `#yy` (where # is the number of lines you want to copy). The copy command (yank) is also `:#1,#2y`, where #1 is the start line and #2 is the end line. You can also make a selection with visual block (`ctrl+v`) or select (`gh`) then yank the selected text with `y`.

Comment: This does not work for me :(

Comment: @cirrusio Please run `:checkhealth` command inside neovim, it should point out the problem maybe.

Answer (score 4):

OS: Ubuntu
In case `set clipboard+=unnamedplus` doesn't work, try installing [xclip](https://opensource.com/article/19/7/xclip):

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

xclip is in the list of clipboard-tools mentioned in the [neovim docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/provider.html#provider-clipboard).

See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/neovim-clipboard-selection